# How to cancelled previous api from components when users changed route in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, dom, redux

I have got two components. For example,

```
   <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
      
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
```

Home.js

```
const Home = ()=>{
  const [count, setCount] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://test.com/home").then(res=>console.log(res))
  });
 return(
  <div>test-1</div>
)
}
```

About.js

```
    const About = ()=>{
      const [count, setCount] = useState([]);
      useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://test.com/about").then(res=>console.log(res))
      });
     return(
      <div>test-2</div>
    )
}
```

Problem:

Here are two components Home.js and about.js When I go to Home component then it's fetched https://test.com/home in the browser and when I go to about component, then it should fetch only this API https://test.com/about.

However, I saw a previous API also called from the browser. Here is two endpoints see currently in the browser.
https://test.com/home
https://test.com/about

How can I cancelled the previous API from the browser when I change the route?

Comment: If you are using axios, see https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
const createAxiosGroup = () => {
  //last.source is a source to cancel last request
  //  initial value is a dummy
  const last = { source: { cancel: () => 0 } };
  return (...args) => {
    //cancel last request
    last.source.cancel();
    //set last source. To be used in current request
    last.source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    const argCopy = [...args];
    argCopy[1] = {
      ...argCopy[1],
      cancelToken: last.source.token,
    };
    //pass args with cancelToken in second argument
    return axios.get(...argCopy);
  };
};
//axios.get grouped so it'll cancel any previously
//  active requests
const grouped = createAxiosGroup();
const Home = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    grouped('https://test.com/home').then((res) =>
      console.log(res)
    );
  });
  return <div>test-1</div>;
};

const About = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    grouped('https://test.com/about').then((res) =>
      console.log(res)
    );
  });
  return <div>test-2</div>;
};
```